# Counting duplicates in C

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates

If I have an array set up as:

```
test[10] = {1,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,3,2}
```

I want to return the number 3 since there is a duplicate 1, a duplicate 2 and a duplicate 3. How can I achieve this? Efficiency doesn't matter.

Comment: Sort it and then checking for duplicates is trivial.

Comment: Suppose that the list were extended with another 3; would you want the answer 3 or 4?

Comment: If another 3 was added the duplicates would be 4

Comment: Arrays are a fixed size.

Comment: There's no need to sort (see Mani's answer, and my comment under infihorz' answer). But you'll never get the right answer because you've tried to put 11 numbers into an array of 10 elements. However, this is a real question; that's not a valid reason to close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must sort the array so it is easier to find duplicates.

Here is an example of a sort (bubble sort):

```
void bubbleSort(int numbers[], int array_size) {
    int i, j, temp;

    for (i = (array_size - 1); i > 0; i--) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (numbers[j-1] > numbers[j]) {
                temp = numbers[j-1];
                numbers[j-1] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then loop through it again and find if the `values[i]` is `==` to `values[i+1]`

**Note:** when you create your for loop make it 1 length shorter to compensate for `values[i+1]` so it does not go out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code ,

```
int main()
{
 int test[10] = {1,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,3,2};
 int i,j,dupliCount = 0;
 for (i =0; i<(sizeof(test)/sizeof(int));i++)
  {
  for(j=i+1;j<(sizeof(test)/sizeof(int));j++)
   {
    if (test[i] == test[j])
     {
      ++dupliCount;
      break;
     }
   }
  }
printf("duplicate count %d",dupliCount);
}
```

Comment: sorry. Now see my edited code.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to debug this. Because it should be `int test[11] = {1,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,3,2}` not `int test[10]`. Each element has a subscription of 0 to 10. So there's altogether 11 elements.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define LEN (11)
    int test[LEN] = {1,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,3,2};
    void sort(int n, int *test){//sort them, use whatever you like
        int i,j,y;
        for (i=0;i<n;++i){
            for (j=i+1;j<n;++j)
                if (test[i]>test[j]){
                    y=test[i];
                    test[i]=test[j];
                    test[j]=y;
                }
            }
    }
    int main(){
        sort(LEN,test);//sort first
        int cnt = 0 , i ;
        for(i=1;i<LEN;++i)
            cnt += (test[i]==test[i-1]);//count duplicates
        printf("%d\n",cnt);//print result

    }
```

Comment: Better: `int test[] = {1,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,3,2}; #define LEN (sizeof test/sizeof *test)`. And bubble sort sucks.

Comment: @JimBalter Bubble-sort is easier to implement and the example sequence is very short. I can't imagine anyone capable of understanding `qsort` failing to come up with a solution to this **duplicate-count** problem.

Comment: You don't have to understand qsort, you just have to call it. Regardless, bubble sort is *bad* and no one should ever be exposed to it. But ... yours is not the evil bubble sort; my mistake; it's a somewhat less bad selection sort. (The best simple O(n^2) sort is insertion sort.)

Answer (score 1):

If **memory space doesn't matter** (I mean you're **not constrained on memory usage**) but **running time is important** and **you know that the values in the array are not bigger than the size of the array**, then `Bucket Sort` sounds like the guy for the job. it will do the job in O(n) instead of O(nlgn) (if you decide to sort the array first).

```
int main()
{
    int test[LEN] = {1,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,3,2};
    int ndup = 0;
    int bucket_array[LEN] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        if (bucket_array[test[i]]++) {
            ndup++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d duplicates\n", ndup);
    return 0;
}
```

i haven't compiled it but i guess it should do the job.

**note**: big thanks to jim balter for his useful comment.

Comment: You're closer than these ridiculous O(n^2) sorts, but you don't have to sort at all ... `int buckets[MAXVAL+1] = {0}; int ndups = 0; for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) if (buckets[i]++) ndups++; printf("%d duplicates\n", ndups);`